# What to call someone who gives as much as he demands?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What to call someone who (can) give (in return) as much as he demands?

Speaking in terms of life and personality.

For example, I ask my future partner to be tidy, glamorous, rich, caring, pretty etc. On the other hand I am, myself that sort of person as well and my partner can, hence, be certain to get this from me as well. So, I could ask as much from someone as the other person could ask from me as well.

Comment: Do you mean "Someone who can give as much as the other person demands"? And are you talking about money, love, dedication etc?

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example.

Comment: @invoker - I mean someone who demands a lot from the other person to satisfy a lot of his own needs but also gives a lot to satisfy the other person's needs.

Comment: A good paymaster!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call him **a fair , caring** person.

Answer (score -1):

Consider:

**Munificent**

**Beneficent**

**Philanthropic**

**Donator**

A donator donates blood as much as he demands.

Comment: These are appropriate if the person gives *freely*.

Answer (score -1):

One common expression is...

> [*She's **high-maintenance***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%27s%20high%20maintenance%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Sometimes this specifically means *she has **expensive** tastes* (that others have to pay for), but it's often used figuratively to mean *she demands a lot of attention*. And it's *usually* used in contexts where the clear implication is *she's **worth it*** (i.e. - people are willing to "pay the price" because they get something back from her which they value equally highly).